# web service requests authentication django token-api

Tags: python, django, web-services, access-token

I want to implement a web service for an iOS application in django. 
I need some kind of authentication, and I googled and heard good things about django token-api.

The only thing I don't understand, is how I make sure one authenticated user can not perform actions for another.

For example, If i have a view that has the @token-required, that only promises that a valid token has been sent, however someone can just change the PK in the request itself and make changes for another user.

How do I make sure the user who has the token, can only perform actions for himself?

Comment: Are you using a web service framework, such as Tastypie or Django REST Framework ? These make authentication / authorization a breeze and provide many, many features you might end up needing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On a very broad level, you need to distinguish between **authentication** and **authorization**. You can read [this page](https://protect.iu.edu/cybersecurity/authn-authz) as an example, or google it for more, but the basic distinction is that *authentication* determines that a user is who he says he is, while *authorization* determines what a certain user is able to see or do.

As you noted above, you can use the `django-token-api` to help with the *authentication* issue. But once you've determined that, you need to move to *authorization*. This is more an issue of [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) that you can see on a per-user (or per-group) basis for individual objects, views, etc.

As Ambroise noted in the comments, using an API framework can make this easier. [Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions) is the `django-rest-framework` documentation for setting permissions once you have authenticated the user.